# Is a fresh ubuntu VPS running only docker containers secure enough for production, beyond SSH, docker configuration, and updates?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, deployment, vps, cicd

I'm planning to set up a production environment using a VPS with a fresh Ubuntu installation and Docker only. The primary purpose of this VPS is to run Docker containers to host various services alongside implementing GitHub CI/CD for automating the deployment process.

Are there best practices or additional measures I should implement to enhance the security of my setup?

I understand that securing the SSH access, configuring the Docker containers properly, and ensuring regular updates are essential steps for maintaining security.

However, I want to ensure that I'm not overlooking any critical security concerns. Are there any other security considerations I should be aware of when using such a setup? Specifically, I'm interested in learning about potential risks that might arise even when only Docker containers are running on the VPS.